# finding the derivative of a square root function

Tags: calculus

I need to find $y'$ if $y=\sqrt x(x-1)$

I distributed the sqrt of x:
$\sqrt x(x)-\sqrt x$

what do I do now? I need to get rid of the square root in order to find the derivative but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Observe that:
$$
y = \sqrt{x}(x - 1) = x^{1/2}(x^{2/2} - 1) = x^{3/2} - x^{1/2}
$$

Comment: I get where x^3/2 comes from, but why is there the "-x"? if you're just distributing the x^1/2, wouldn't it be "x^3/2 - x^1/2"?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x\sqrt x-\sqrt x$$
$$=x(x^{1 \over 2})-x^{1 \over 2}$$
$$=x^{3 \over2} - x^{\frac 12}$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{3 \over2} - x^{\frac 12}\right) = \dfrac 32x^{\frac 12}-\dfrac 12x^{-\frac 12}$$
$$=\dfrac {3\sqrt x}{2}-\dfrac 1{2\sqrt x}$$
We are technically done, but lets rationalise the denominator
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{3 \over2} - x^{\frac 12}\right) = \dfrac {3\sqrt x}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt x}{2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

First,
$(\sqrt{x})'
=(x^{1/2})'
=(1/2)x^{-1/2}
$
since
$(x^a)'
=a x^{a-1}
$.

By the product rule

$\begin{align}
(\sqrt{x}(x-1))'
&=\sqrt{x}(x-1)' + (\sqrt{x})'(x-1)\\
&=\sqrt{x}+(1/2)x^{-1/2}(x-1)\\
&=\sqrt{x}+(1/2)(x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2})\\
&=\sqrt{x}+(1/2)\sqrt{x}-1/(2\sqrt{x})\\
&=(3/2)\sqrt{x}-1/(2\sqrt{x})\\
&=(3/2)\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}/(2x)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\left(3-\frac{1}{2x}\right)\\
\end{align}
$

Those last three lines
are all, in my opinion,
acceptable ways 
to wrote the result.